# Reading data over serial Arduino and XBee

Tags: arduino

I am having the following:

Two [Arduinos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arduino) and two [XBees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XBee). I want to send data from the one to another. The XBees communicate, because I have the proposes test (connect one XBee with the Arduino and the other to the PC, write from the one, and watch the other in the other terminal).

Now I want to send data from the one to another:

These are my two scripts:

For sending (which is tested in the former test that sends all the letters):

```cpp
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial xbee(2, 3); // RX, TX
char c = 'A';
int  pingPong = 1;

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);

    Serial.println( "Arduino started sending bytes via XBee" );

    //Set the data rate for the SoftwareSerial port
    xbee.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
    // Send character via XBee to other XBee connected to Mac
    // via USB cable.
    xbee.write( c );

    //--- Display the character just sent on console. ---
    Serial.println( c );

    //--- Get the next letter in the alphabet, and reset to ---
    //--- 'A' once we have reached 'Z'.
    c = c + 1;
    if ( c>'Z' )
         c = 'A';

    //--- Switch LED on Arduino board for every character sent---
    if ( pingPong == 0 )
        digitalWrite(13, LOW);
    else
        digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
    pingPong = 1 - pingPong;
    delay( 1000 );
}
```

The problem is when I connected an Arduino to receive data from the other XBee.

Here is my code:

```cpp
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial xbee(2, 3); // RX, TX

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);

    Serial.println( "Arduino started receiving bytes via XBee" );

    // Set the data rate for the SoftwareSerial port.
    xbee.begin(9600);
}

void loop()  {
    int temp = xbee.read();

    Serial.print("Character received:");
    Serial.println(temp);
    delay(1000);
}
```

Output is always:

```
Character received: -1.
```

If I change the `temp` from `int` to `byte` I see `Character received: (a non-[ASCII][3] symbol)`.

I am using XBee series 1.

They are configured through X-CTU, based on the one tutorial found on ladyada.net.

Then I connected the XBee to an Arduino (TX to pin 3, RX to 2, Vcc and GND respectively) and the other XBee to the PC through an [FTDI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FTDI) cable. I was able to send characters from the Arduino and see them in the serial monitor of the X-CTU. Does this mean that they are configured correctly?

Then I wanted to connect an Arduino to my receiver. You can see the code above. I am always getting no available data.

Returned -1 means that there is no data in the serial.

Comment: What Arduino board and version are you using?

Comment: I tried arduino Uno to Uno and rduino Uno to micro.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Changing `int` to `byte` is really changing int to `char`.  The non-[ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) symbols are a result of trying to render the character (`0b11111111`). Negative one (`-1`) in decimal is all ones in binary because `int`'s are signed by default.  Check out [Bin/Dec/Hex Converter](http://www.binaryhexconverter.com/) to verify.

All of that is to say that `xbee.read()` returns a `byte`/`char`. I was not able to find anything in [the documentation](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/SoftwareSerialRead), but I would assume that the `-1` is due to an error (based on the hardware `Serial` [documentation](http://arduino.cc/en/Serial/Read)). This is because there is nothing to read.

### You could try the following:

- Ensure the RX/TX lines are correct. Trust me, it happens.
- Check to see if the XBee has data available prior to reading. (You'll get a lot less lines printed since it will wait until a byte is ready to be read.)

```cpp
if (xbee.available()) {
    byte temp= xbee.read();
    Serial.print(temp);
}
```

- Use the built in (hardware). SoftwareSerial should work, but in my experience, hardware serial is much more reliable.

  - Depending on your model(s) of Arduino, you may have to ([Disable Auto Reset on Serial Connection](http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/DisablingAutoResetOnSerialConnection)). This appears to be only needed if you're trying to send data through the FTDI chip from somewhere other than the IDE's *Serial Monitor* (generally speaking).
- This thread *[Arduino to Arduino XBee Serial Communication](http://arduino.cc/forum/index.php?topic=24061.0)* has a very similar setup that appears to be working. Simplify your effort as much as possible and then slowly add functionality.
- Directly connect the XBee RX & TX lines to a USB-to-FTDI connector, such as [this cable](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9718) or this [breakout board](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9716).

Until you have a working proof of concept, you should make it as simple as possible.  Once it is working then add features one at a time. This seems like what you're doing already, but this could probably be simplified further (cut the Arduinos out of the equation by using FTDI only, use hardware serial, etc.).

It sounds like a pretty cool project. Good luck!

Comment: it always go to the else.. "No data available". With FTDI only it works.

Comment: If FTDI works then try using the Arduino's Hardware serial.  I have a suspicion that the problem is somewhere in the use of `SoftwareSerial` or a mixup of the RX/TX lines.  (Possibly both).  You could try your Arduino in [tristate](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/27774/10697) mode to make sure your RX/TX lines are correct when using hardware serial.  Once that's settled, you can begin debugging your code.

Comment: I tried changing the ports (TX and RX) in case I have connected them wrong but still no change. I will check again this with Hardware Serial.

Comment: I cannot find any examples on how to use hardware seral? what do you mean?

Comment: [Here](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/serial) is the program documentation.  Hardware serial means that you connect the serial lines of the xbee to `"tx->1"` and `"rx<-0"` (http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardUno) (top right hand corner of the board)

Comment: Hardware Serial does not work either. So where to check for the problem? Does the fact that they speak with the FTDI means that they are correclty configured or not?

Comment: @ghostrider From your feedback, it seems that the Xbees are configured correctly.  Instead of going through the xbee's perhaps you should try getting your program to work by connecting them directly (tx -> rx) and (rx -> tx).  Once this works, I would put one arduino into tristate mode and hook your FTDI to the other one.  Once you have at least one working across the Xbee swap it out for the other one.  This will show whether or not both are working.  Once you verified they both work separately, across the XBee, start adding components.

Comment: it does not work even connecting them direclty. it should be pretty easy I do not get what is going on right now :/

Comment: @ghostrider This is the first thing you want to overcome.  It is probably something trivial (it usually is for me) that takes two weeks to find.  Validate your cables are correctly connected and your hardware is alright by putting the arduinos in tristate mode.  See [here](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/27774/10697) for more.

Comment: I finally added. Didn't change any code, but bought new wires and now it is ok. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

```
void loop()  {
    unsigned char temp; = 
    if (Serial.available() > 0){
       temp = xbee.read();
       Serial.print("Character received:");
       Serial.println(temp,HEX);
}
```

try this code.
I converted your int temp to unsigned char to handle MSB. It works for me. But I used Xbee series 2 and hardware serial. Anyway, data handling is maters.

Answer (score 0):

i know its kinda late, but maybe there still someone who in need for this solution at the moment.

```
if (xbee.available()) {
    byte temp= xbee.read();
    Serial.print(temp);
}
```

for this code here at the reciving part, i change `serial.print(tempt)` to `serial.write(tempt)`. the reasons is its kinda display ASCII code when i use `serial.print(variablesname)`, but when i use `serial.write(variablesname)` it display as it suppose to. can try it out if any of you still stuck at this prob.